Replacing brake lever on Shimano Nexus integrated shifter/brake lever
I have a Shimano Nexus Revoshift shifter with brake lever, part number SB-C6000-8, to use with a Nexus 8 internally geared hub. The brake lever has been sheared off where it joins the body of the mechanism when the weight of the bike fell on it during a crash.
Is it possible to procure and install a replacement brake lever, or will I need to replace the entire brake lever/shifter unit? The brake lever itself looks fairly standard, but I cannot find documentation of this. I may be able to get a "generic" lever from the scrap bike stream, but I doubt I'd be able to find this exact one.
Also, I am not sure how to disassemble the unit to access and replace the lever; I can't find that documented anywhere either, so if anyone knows that that would also be useful.
Image Source: https://bike.shimano.com/en-NZ/product/component/nexus-c6000-int8/SB-C6000-8.html

Welcome to the site - excellent question and well described.  I've added a photo and a link to this particular shifter.  If its not the right one, please used [edit] to add a photo of your one.

Any basic brake lever will work.
If your shifter is undamaged besides the lever being broken off, it is possible to clean it up and reuse it.
If your shifter is damaged you could search for a basic shifter model# SL-C6000-8 and use whatever brake levers you want.
